# Rust Getter - return type

Tags: object, rust

Is there a way to replace in a "getter" method the return type

```
pub struct Foo {
  key: MyKey,
  value: usize,
}


impl Foo {
  pub fn value(&self) -> usize {
    ...
  }
}
```

by something like:

```
pub fn value(&self) -> Typeof(Self.value) { ... }
```

Thanks

Comment: There is not unless you make your own macro to implement it. AFAIK

Comment: Making the signature of a `pub fn` depend on the type of a non-`pub` field seems like the opposite of a good idea.

Comment: Agree with the comment above. It's something that feels convenient (not having to change the return type whenever you change the type of the variable) but for a public interface you'd really want this to be inconvenient. Changing the API and ABI will most likely break any code that uses this function.

Answer (score 1):

No, Rust doesn't have anything like this. You can generate getters using a macro, if you want to save typing.